# Strange issue in Excel. Different results after 10th decimal place when multiplying same numbers in the same excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Strange issue in Excel. Different results after 10th decimal place when multiplying same numbers in the same excel sheet. Attached is the excel sheet screenshot and also the link to the excel sheet itself. Why the difference.

Can you please help. Thanks

[image]

[Link to Excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jw3LG_5iRFssgOFjsYqRRZI3iGfzduYa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104878018080513169323&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: This question seems to relate to Google Sheets. If that's correct, please edit the title and description accordingly. Excel and Google Sheets are not the same thing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result Excel stores numbers as doubles, which gives a limit to how precise a calculation can be.

Comment: Hi @NeilT 
This is not a google sheets question.
You can download the excel file from the link provided. Thanks

Comment: @DS_London Thanks for your reply.
Here the precision is breaking after 10th decimal place which is not acceptable. 

Is there a logical explanation to my query?

Thanks

Comment: Your statement that "breaking after the 10th decimal place ... is not acceptable" indicates that using Excel will be problematic for your use case. Excel displays numbers up to 15 significant figures and no more. Rounding is by truncation, meaning that a decimal point followed by twenty 9's will be truncated to a decimal point followed by fifteen 9's (plus trailing zeroes, depending on your display). You cannot perform operations to a greater precision using Excel (at least not in a straightforward manner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the discrepancy is that **the two numbers in column H (153095.044...) are not really the same**.

There are two key things to understand here:

1. **Excel displays numbers using a maximum of 15 significant figures.** (Rounding depends on the number's source; user-entered numbers are simply truncated, meaning that the 16th and subsequent significant figures are displayed as zeros.)
2. **Excel stores numbers using up to 17 significant figures.**

A corollary of these is that two numbers may be *different* in a raw Excel file (and Excel's memory) but appear *identical* when displayed in a worksheet, even at maximum display precision.

This is exactly what is happening in your case. Looking at the raw XML, the two numbers are as follows (with some intermediate elements omitted):

```
<row r="26" ... >
    <c r="H26" s="4">
        <v>153095.04486992653</v>
    </c>
</row>
<row r="27" ...>
    <c r="H27" s="6">
        <v>153095.04486992667</v>
    </c>
</row>
```

You can clearly see that these two numbers (comprising 17 digits) are different. This is why your multiplications in column I produce different results. However, to 15 sig fig the numbers are identical, which is why they display identically in column H in your worksheet.

You can read more about numeric precision in Excel [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel), but this article doesn't cover point #2 above. For that, you could read [this answer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/numbers-stored-in-xml-file/m-p/3767502).

In case this second link disappears in future, I will quote the key parts:

> Contrary to most online documentation (including MSFT's), numbers are
> not "stored with 15 significant decimal digits of precision".
>
> Instead, numbers are represented in a binary form in memory, called
> 64-bit binary floating-point.  And since most decimal fractions (e.g.
> 0.999) cannot be represented exactly in that binary form, they are approximated by the sum of 53 consecutive powers of 2.
>
> The reason that we see only up to 15 significant digits in Excel is
> because Excel arbitrary limits the display and formatting of numbers
> to that many digits.
>
> But in fact, the 64BFP standard states that it requires 17 significant
> digits, rounded, in order to convert between all decimal and binary
> representations with no loss of precision.
>
> So, Excel usually writes up to 17 significant digits into XML files.

If you require greater precision then unfortunately Excel may not be suitable for your use case.